# Handling security token failure in MVI Kotlin Application

Tags: android, kotlin

I have a custom application built in Kotlin follwing MVI using a single activity.

Basic pattern of ViewModel -> Repository -> Rertofit API

The user logs in and is issued a token, this token is then used on all subsequent API calls. Eventually this token expires or can be expired in the backend.

I am trying to figure out how to handle the expired token in a clean manner at a low level and not pollute all my fragments with logic on handling an expired token.

If the token expires I want the user to be taken to the login page/fragment.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I think it could be done. First, define an interface that provides a contract for logout. For example:

```
interface LogOutOwner {
    fun logout(): Observable<Unit>
}
```

Implement this interface, here I am using an interceptor as an implementation since it gives enough information to deduce if logout is needed:

```
class ErrorInterceptor : Interceptor, LogOutOwner {

    private val publishLogOutSubject: PublishSubject<Unit> = PublishSubject.create()

    override fun intercept(chain: Interceptor.Chain): Response {
        val response = chain.proceed(chain.request())
        if (response.code == 401) { // check if a logout is needed
            publishLogOutSubject.onNext(Unit)
        }
        return response
    }

    override fun logout(): Observable<Unit> {
        return publishLogOutSubject
    }
}
```

In order for this to work your interceptor and `LogOutOwner` should be singletons, so they handle all your network requests. One of the ways you can achieve this is by using a dependency injection framework. Here as an example, I show manual dependency injection:

```
object Injection {
    private val errorInterceptor = ErrorInterceptor()

    fun provideLogOutOwner(): LogOutOwner = errorInterceptor

    private fun provideOkHttpClient(): OkHttpClient {
        val httpClient = OkHttpClient.Builder()
        httpClient.addInterceptor(errorInterceptor)
        return httpClient.build()
    }

    fun provideRetrofit() = Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl("")
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .client(provideOkHttpClient())
            .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create())
            .build()
}
```

Since `Kotlin`'s **object** has only one instance, `errorInterceptor` is also instantiated only once in the scope of `Injection`.
Finally, now you need to subscribe to `LogOutOwner` to listen for logout events. Since you have only one activity you can subscribe there and open whatever fragment you need. But by doing so you eventually need to handle canceling the logout subscription and whenever you want to handle logout on a different activity or a fragment you would need to implement the same canceling logic. To make it more universal, without introducing the same boilerplate whenever you need to handle a logout consider using [lifecycle-aware components](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/lifecycle). Here is an example:

```
    class LogOutObserver(
    private val logOutOwner: LogOutOwner,
    private val logoutAction: () -> Unit
) :
    LifecycleObserver {

    private var disposable: Disposable? = null

    @OnLifecycleEvent(Lifecycle.Event.ON_START)
    fun onStart() {
        disposable = logOutOwner.logout()
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe { logoutAction.invoke() }
    }

    @OnLifecycleEvent(Lifecycle.Event.ON_STOP)
    fun onStop() {
        disposable?.dispose()
    }
}
```

When you need to handle logout, just use this observer as here:

```
lifecycle.addObserver(LogOutObserver(Injection.provideLogOutOwner()) {
    // do logout
})
```

So by introducing all the code above we reduced the amount of logic an activity or fragment should implement. Basically, activity or fragment now need only to concern themselves with the navigation logic without worrying about what causes the logout or any lifecycle events.
I used RxJava here but I imagine it's not that hard to implement it with Kotlin Coroutines if needed.

P.S. If you need it to use with multiple fragments/activities you need to change `LogOutObserver` so that it subscribes/cancels subscription in `onResume()` and `onPause()` to prevent from calling logout action from multiple activities/fragments at the same time.

Comment: I am using my own call adapter similar to what is documented [here](https://proandroiddev.com/create-retrofit-calladapter-for-coroutines-to-handle-response-as-states-c102440de37a) to handle all error response.

Comment: It seems like you could use the same call adapter and propagate the authorization error inside of ApiError up to your ViewModel. But still, you would have to handle this error in your ViewModel since you want to do a log out which requires a context.

Comment: Yes I can but I was trying to avoid having to duplicate that logic in all the ViewModels

Comment: You don't have to duplicate it. You can just extract the method that checks the type of an error to the base ViewModel or just write an extension function if you are using kotlin. But in any way, if you need to do a logout you need to have a context which means you need somehow to pass your control flow to activity/fragment because passing context to your network classes is a bad practice, it reduces testability.

Comment: Anyway if you don't want it in your ViewModel, there is one other way I see it could be done. You can handle it in your repository but that means you have to pollute your repository's interface with a method for log out or you have to use a concrete repository's implementation in your activities/fragments. Ping me if you want more details on that. P.S. Do you have a BaseActivity that you extend by all your activities?

Comment: I am using a single activity architecture, but I do have a BaseFragment and BaseViewModel

Comment: @mfleshman I edited the answer, instead of changing the repository's interface I took a slightly different approach.

Comment: I am not sure I follow your example fully.